# Some questions regarding SE network statistics on about page

Tags: discussion, tour, network-statistics

About us of both SE and SO shows "2015 Stack Exchange Network Statistics" with same figures.

- I think both can show their statistics i.e "SO statistics on SO about page" and "SE statistics on SE about page".
- Why do statistics show only "Registered Stack Overflow users" (not SE in-spite of being SE statistics)? We can mention SO specific figure in brackets like have been doing for "Pageviews" figure.
- When are we going to update it to "201**6** Stack Exchange Network Statistics"?

Thanks.

Comment: Now the *2018 Stack Exchange Network Overview* is updated in the [SE About](https://stackexchange.com/about) page.

Comment: @Arulkumar Nice!